# Why is std::sort() faster than std::make_heap()?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, vector

I have `13721057` elements in my `std::vector<Sequence>`. I need to sort this vector and grab the first 25 elements. I thought, since you can build a heap in `O(N)` it must be faster to pop 25 elements (each being `O(logN)`) than sorting the whole vector in `O(NlogN)`.

However, when I time the code:

```
clock_t tStart = clock();
sort(mostFrequent.begin(), mostFrequent.end(), greater<Sequence>());
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

vs.

```
clock_t tStart = clock();
make_heap(mostFrequent.begin(), mostFrequent.end());
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

It appears to be much faster to sort the whole vector. Why is this?

Comment: What are the times for both?

Comment: Maybe hidden constant. Try to test std::nth_element() also.

Comment: Did you run this more than once?  Did you change which one is called first?  Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Also, it might be faster to `std::partition` to find the 25th element.

Comment: I've tried a lot of times. They are not in the same execution block, I am commenting in/out. Not sure about optimizations in CLion, I will check
sort: is about 0.5s
make_heap: is about 2s

Comment: Big-oh notation throws away all the constants... For example, even if quicksort is O(n log n), O(n^2) algorithms are usually faster for small arrays. I'm not saying that it is what we are seeing here, but you must keep it in mind when reasoning about asymptotic behavior.

Comment: 0.5s for 13M elements sounds suspiciously fast.

Comment: @MatteoItalia These are sufficiently large inputs. Constants won't matter here probably.

Comment: Why didn't you provide the same comparison functor to both `std::sort` and `std::make_heap`?

Comment: @erip that's easy to just posit, but what sufficiently large inputs are depends on the constants, so we have a circular argument here. A 13M element matrix certainly wouldn't be "sufficiently large" to make Coppersmith–Winograd attractive, for one. I would have expected it to be enough here, but..

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, it's part of the class. < operator. I change it in the real comparison.

Comment: @Murat Ayan:  I don't understand your answer.  In one case, you provided a comparison functor.  In the other case, you did not.  So the two cases are using different comparison rules, which throws any sort of timing results into question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy `make_heap` uses the overriden `<` operator inside the class. I needed to pass the greater into the `sort` function. (Greater or Less doesn't change the timing btw). So both runs the same code internally.

Comment: Please, give us additional information: compiler you are using (and version), compilation flags, some detail about comparison function (is it expensive?) and Sequence class (how big is it, is it copyable/movable and are copy and move expensive?).

Comment: @IlyaPopov: `g++ 4.2.1`, `-O3 -Wall -std=c++0x `, Comparison function just compares two integers. Class consists of one 30 letter string and a small integer.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. But is there any specific reason why you use so old compiler (it was released in 2007, ages before c++11)?

Comment: Are you sure about the compiler version? My g++ 4.2.3 doesn't recognize `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @MarkB I did a `g++ --version`. I think it came with the XCode because I didn't specifically used it before as I'm not developing C++ usually. Latest CLion gives the same result, I don't know what compiler it uses.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a full answer but to get the first 25 elements out of 13721057 you better use [`partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

If you only need the 25th element, then [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

As a side note. For getting the first elements less than X in sorted order, I would do `auto mid = std::partition` with a lambda, and then `std::sort(begin,mid)`. There may be a better way.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for! Not `std::partition`. :)

Comment: nth_element(): "All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element." I think this will be the fastest method with least hidden constant. And you can sort first 25 elements after.

Comment: Thank you guys, `partial_sort` sure is faster. But I still don't get why `sort` is much faster, since `partial_sort` is what I am trying to implement eventually with the heap.

Comment: @JohanLundberg nth_element implemented like quicksort (super fast), and costs O(N) time. sorting 25 elements: O(25 * log25) (only need to do once, not so much). Sorry, but I will bet on O(13721057) + O(25 * log25) instead of O(13721057 * log25)

Comment: @SashaMN a big O with constants filled in is fairly meaningless

Comment: @MuratAyan Actually, `partial_sort` is [implemented](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1923) in terms of `make_heap` in libstdc++, GCC's standard library. Thus, if `partial_sort` is fast, so must be `make_heap`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov This is a different algorithm, then in question. make_heap() works on 25 first elements, and the algorithm maintains heap after.

Comment: @IlyaPopov: My plan was to make a max heap of 25, however, while trying things out, I've come across to this anomaly.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: As suggested in a comment I also tried with a pre-sorted input and in that case I *did* manage to get sort faster than make_heap for my "expensive to copy" type, but only by a small margin around 5-10%.

No matter what I try, I am unable to reproduce your results on either Solaris or Linux (gcc 4.4). `make_heap` has always come out on the order of 1/3rd the time spent.

- No optimization vs -O3 only changes total time, not relative order.
- I used your exact number of items.
- First tried sorting `int` then a larger "expensive to copy" class.
- Guessed what includes you were using.
- Moved timing calls outside the printf to make sure they were always ordered properly.

I assume that the actual reason for this discrepancy is that either your `<` and `>` operators aren't the same complexity or that copying your object is somehow expensive relative to comparing it in a way my test was unable to duplicate.

Comment: Did you try the "expensive to copy" class with a presorted vector? (That should be close to optimal for sort and pessimal for heap, assuming you're using OP's technique of using `std::less` for sort and `std::greater` for heap, which produces identical results.)

Comment: @rici A presorted vector is notionally quick sort's worst case so I didn't try that variation. If I get a few moments I'll try to test that case too.

Comment: That depends on the strategy for identifying the pivot. If you use the midpoint element as the pivot, then it is optimal. If you use a random pivot, it's still pretty good, and still has the advantage of not doing any swaps during the partition operation. (I didn't test with expensive copies, but with long longs, it reduced std::sort from 1.22 to 0.30 seconds. It also hugely increased the cost of partial_sort.)

Comment: @Mark B: "A presorted vector is notionally quick sort's worst case" – Only if the first or last element of the range is chosen as the pivot, and no one can possibly be stupid enough to do that. [Ok, let's say almost no one.]

Comment: @ArneVogel It depends a lot on what type of partitioning algorithm is used, honestly. Median of 3 or random partitioning algorithms tend to work well with mostly sorted inputs.